# Show $\mathbb{E}[X] \le \mathbb{E}[Y]$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, continuity, density-function

I have a problem that I'm having trouble to identify the correct integral intervals for proof. I would like to have some help on the thought process.

> **Problem:**
>   Let $X$ and $Y$ have densities $f$ and $g$, respectively, and 
>   $f(x)  
> \begin{cases}
> \ge g(x),  & \text{if $x$ }\le a;\\
> \le g(x), & \text{if $x$ }\ge a
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> Show that $\mathbb{E}[X] \le \mathbb{E}[Y]$

Since $\mathbb{E}[X]= \displaystyle  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\, dx$

I will have to identify intervals (one positive and one negative) that are able to prove $\mathbb{E}[X] \le \mathbb{E}[Y]$ for all cases. However, I feel there may be an intersection, which leads to 3 intervals total, but I'm not sure how to divide up the segments. I would like some help with laying out the proof.

Comment: No, $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\; f(x)\; dx$.  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\; dx = 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry about the typo, still familiarizing with MathJax.

Comment: A quick proof is to note that the hypothesis implies that the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are such that $$F_X\geqslant F_Y$$ everywhere and to recall that expectations have simple expressions in terms of CDFs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

W.l.o.g. let be $a=0$ (otherwise shift the random variables, see Addendum). Then 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx & = \int_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)\,dx + \int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx \\[12pt]
& \leq \int_{-\infty}^0 xg(x)\,dx + \int_0^\infty xg(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xg(x)\,dx
\end{align}
holds.

**Addendum** (maybe some extra notes about the "$a=0$" assumption above do not harm): With the linearity of the expectation value the following equivalence holds
$$\Bbb E(X-a)\leq \Bbb E(Y-a) \Leftrightarrow \Bbb E(X)-a\leq \Bbb E(Y)-a \Leftrightarrow \Bbb E(X)\leq \Bbb E(Y),$$
which justifies just to consider the translated variables.
For the CDF of $X-a$ (and for $Y-a$ analogously) we have
$$P_X(X-a\leq x) = P_X(X\leq x+a) = \int_{-\infty}^{x+a}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x+a)\,dx.$$
For the translated desnsity function $f(x+a)$ (this is the density function of $X-a$) we obtain now
$$f(x+a)
\begin{cases}
\ge g(x+a),  & \text{if $x$ }\le 0\\
\le g(x+a), & \text{if $x$ }\ge 0
\end{cases}.$$
This allows us just to study the case $a=0$.

Comment: Hi, do we have to add the difference between G(x) and f(x) that is the area under the intersecting point?

Comment: @lydias : You shouldn't write $G(x)$ if you mean $g(x).$ The area under just one point is $0. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks Michael. For some reason my cellphone keyboard just wanted to capitalize that G lol okay it did it again.

Comment: Since there seems to be some general interest about the questen, I've formulated the shifting argument. Thanks @MichaelHardy for the formatting improvement. ;)